# Calculate average in a table

Tags: javascript, html-table, average

Is it possible to calculate the average grade.. of the tables?
I only found answers with input fields.
I want to show the average at the footer in "totalAvg".
I don't know if it's possible with a jQuery-Plugin?

```
 <table class="kader">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="head">
                <th colspan="1">Nr</th>
                <th colspan="1">Gegner</th>
                <th colspan="1">Tore</th>
                <th colspan="1"><span class="positionc pos_11">11</span></th>
                <th colspan="1">Asissts</th>
                <th colspan="1"><span class="positionc pos_yc"></span></th>
                <th colspan="1"><span class="positionc pos_yc"></span> <span class="positionc pos_rc"></span></th>
                <th colspan="1"><span class="positionc pos_rc"></span></th>
                <th colspan="1">Grade 1</th>
                <th colspan="1">Grade 2</th>
                <th colspan="1">Grade 3</th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
<tr>
                    <td>1.</td> 
                    <td>FC Augsburg</a></td>
                    <td class="mini_note">-</td>
                    <td class="mini_note">-</td>
                    <td class="mini_note">-</td>
                    <td class="mini_note">-</td>
                    <td class="mini_note">-</td>
                    <td class="mini_note">-</td>
                    <td class="mini_note"><span class="position pos_y">3</span></td>
                    <td class="mini_note"><span class="position pos_y">3,5</span></td>
                    <td class="mini_note"><span class="position pos_y">3</span></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2.</td> 
                    <td>1899 Hoffenheim</td>
                    <td class="mini_note">-</td>
                    <td class="mini_note">-</td>
                    <td class="mini_note">-</td>
                    <td class="mini_note">-</td>
                    <td class="mini_note">-</td>
                    <td class="mini_note">-</td>
                    <td class="mini_note"><span class="position pos_y">4</span></td>
                    <td class="mini_note"><span class="position pos_r">4,5</span></td>
                    <td class="mini_note"><span class="position pos_y">4</span></td>

                </tr>



                            </tbody>
                                <tbody>
                <tr class="footer">
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <th colspan="1" class="totalAvg"></th>
                <th colspan="1" class="totalAvg"></th>
                <th colspan="1" class="totalAvg"></th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some piece of code you need to change to fit your exact needs.

```
var sums = [];
var counts = [];

$('tr:not(.head)').each(function(){
  $(this).children('td').each(function(index){
    var value = +$(this).text().replace(',', '.');
    sums[index] = (sums[index] || 0) + (isNaN(value) ? 0 : value);
    counts[index] = (counts[index] || 0) + (isNaN(value) ? 0 : 1);
  });
});

$('table tbody').last().append('<tr id="averages">');
sums.forEach(function(item, index) {
  $('#averages').append($('<td>').html(sums[index]/counts[index]));
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/oMOWOmo/2/edit

PS: I know it computes the average for the Number column. I thought it was better this way.

PSS: If your table was structured better, the solution would be much simpler and straightforward.